# Translate app Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, translation

I know it's a simple question but I don't know how to solve it.

Since now, I have had my app published in Spanish, but I want to translate it to English. So I translated the string resources file and I exported the apk twice, once in Spanish and another one in English. I don't know how to publish both apk or what I need to do to translate the app... I didn't find info about how to do this without paying an oficial translation service...

Thanks for help!

Comment: There is a biultin i18n (internationalization) mechanism in android. You should include language-targeted strings.xml in special folders like values-en, values-sp etc. But if u really need to publish different app for different languages you should change the package name to make it unique for every app. like my.app_en.android and my.app_sp.android or my.app.android.en/my.app.android.sp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't do that way. Use such types of different xmls in your project to translate strings

```
res/values/strings.xml
res/values-fr/strings.xml
```

You can refere here..
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html